# #powershell storing and retrieving values from/to array or a hash table

Tags: arrays, powershell

I wondering if there's a way to store/retrieve data in a hash table or an array. For instance,

```
 $a = get-process
```

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName                                                                                                            
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     --  -- -----------                                                                                                            
    156       9     1924        220 ...23     0.06   3788   4 ActionUriServer                                                                                                        
    364      19    10676      22196 ...01     0.75  11432   4 ApplicationFrameHost                                                                                                   
    155       9     6360      10388 ...98     5.47  14940   0 audiodg
```

I need this to be stored in a variable. When I want this to be retried, I should be able to use the index value.
for e.g.

```
 $a[1][1]
```

should fetch me the value 'Handles'

I roughly have an idea about multi dimensional arrays, but then, not really sure how to push these values to the variable and have it indexed.

will

```
 foreach
```

workout ?

Comment: `$a[1].Handles` would retrieve you the handles. Not sure what else you are trying to achieve. Can you explain what *actual* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Wait, do you want `$a[1][1]` to re-run the `Get-Process` command and get you updated data?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh: It looks like the OP is looking for the _literal_ (string) 'Handles', based on parsing the _text_ output by the default formatting, as printed. Why that is desired is indeed worth explaining.

Comment: Why are you trying to parse and object array? There is not need.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to parse the *formatted output* rather than operate on the *objects* returned by `Get-Process` (or customize formatting using one of the `Format-*` cmdlets), you can try this:

```
Get-Process | Out-String -Stream | % { $a = @() } { $a += $null; $a[-1] = -split $_  }
```

- `Out-String -Stream` is required to obtain the formatted-for-output string representations of the objects returned by `Get-Process`, and `-Stream` passes each resulting line individually through the pipeline (by default, `Out-String` passes the *entire* resulting string *at once*).
- The above is simple, but not efficient, because the array is recreated for each input line; to remedy that, you could use a `[System.Collections.Generic.List[string[]]]` instance instead.
- PowerShell arrays are `0`-based, so it'll be `$a[1][0]` that contains `Handles`

  - (The reason that it is *row* `1` is that the formatted output starts with a *blank line*, but that could easily be fixed.)